# What is the meaning of the third number in the following code?

Tags: netlogo

```
nw:generate-small-world nations links 8 8 5 false[]
```

The first two numbers are clear to me, but the third one has never been explained to me at university.

Answer (score 1):

The [NetLogo documentation for `nw` says](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#nw:generate-small-world):

> *`nw:generate-small-world turtle-breed link-breed row-count column-count
>   clustering-exponent is-toroidal optional-command-block`*
>
> Generates a new small-world network using the Kleinberg Model. Note
>   that nw:generate-watts-strogatz generates a more traditional
>   small-world network.
>
> The algorithm proceeds by generating a lattice of the given number of
>   rows and columns (the lattice will wrap around itself if is-toroidal
>   is true). The “small world effect” is created by adding additional
>   links between the nodes in the lattice. The higher the
>   clustering-exponent, the more the algorithm will favor already
>   close-by nodes when adding new links. A clustering exponent of 2.0 is
>   typically used.

That links to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_routing#The_Kleinberg_Model) for a little more information on the model used:

> When adding edges, the probability of connecting some random vertex `v` to another random vertex `w` is proportional to `1 / d(v, w)^q`, where `q` is the clustering coefficient and `d` is the distance function.